# replace multiple line breaks with one new line charatcer in oracle server using REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: oracle10g, newline, regexp-replace

How to replace multiple line breaks with one new line charatcer in **oracle server** using REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: please let me know the answer if anyone knows

Comment: You need to show a before/after data example to illustrate the problem you are trying to solve. Please edit your post to show this, and add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.  Dealing with carriage returns can get tricky depending if you are on Windows or UNIX but you'll get the idea.  This was run in Toad, which uses a regular expression which looks for occurrences of two or more newline characters in a row and replaces them with one newline.

[image]