# how to search for multiple newline characters followed by specific string

Tags: regex, plsql

This is about PLSQL.

I have to search for below pattern and replace them with a space.

```
\n\n\nnotes://MYTEST/\n\n
```

e.g source string is something like:

```
source = "My string\n\n\nnotes://MYTEST/\n\nMy string continues"
```

result of the replace should produce:

```
result = "My string My string continues"
```

I would like to know how to get this done.

I have tried `'[^\n]notes://MYTEST/'`, but it doesn't work it seems.

I would like to see an answer with a little bit of explanation so that I can learn as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to concatenate the newline character when building your search string like this using the CHR() function:

[image]

Note the plus sign in the regex means "one or more" of the previous character (the newline).  To specify 2 or more use `{2,}` instead as illustrated here: [replace multiple line breaks with one new line charatcer in oracle server using REGEXP_REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518929/replace-multiple-line-breaks-with-one-new-line-charatcer-in-oracle-server-using/32527929#32527929)

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure about your database's syntax, but for plain old PCRE regex, your attempt is looking for the string preceded by *anything but* a newline. Try this:

```
\n+notes://MYTEST/
```

https://regex101.com/r/yO4eX1/1

Note the slashes there are escaped; it looks like this isn't a requirement for your application though, based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
select regexp_replace(column_name,'(\\n)+notes://MYTEST/(\\n)+', ' ')
from table;

(\\n)                   :\ is operator and should be escaped by another \
    +                   :matches one or more of previous pattern group
notes://MYTEST/         :exact match of your string
(\\n)                   :\ is operator and should be escaped by another \
    +                   :matches one or more of previous pattern group
```